# Getting request timeout error in python request

Tags: python-requests

I am sending this request but getting timeout.

```py
import requests
   
value = 'Hi'
 
token = ' ' 
id = '' 
tele = (f'https://api.telegram.org/bot/{token}/sendMessage?chat_id={id}&text={value}')
req=requests.post(tele)
```

[image: output this]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass valid token id in order to connect to API.